# Jinja2 set default value to include if failed

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to run this:

```
{%- include '{name}.sql'.format(name=name) -%}
```

but the thing is, from time to time the files I will try to include won't exist.

I've found this as a solution to catch the exception and return value:

```
{%- include '{name}.sql'.format(name=name) ignore missing -%}
```

and it does catch the exceptions, but the thing is that it has a default value of `''`,

How can I set the default value of whatever I want?

Answer (score 1):

As raised in the documentation:

> You can also provide a list of templates that are checked for existence before inclusion. The first template that exists will be included. If *ignore missing* is given, it will fall back to rendering nothing if none of the templates exist, otherwise it will raise an exception.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#include*</sup>

So if you do have a file, let's say *default.sql* that you know from a fact exists, you could do:

```
{%- include ['{name}.sql'.format(name=name), 'default.sql'] -%}
```